# Get the set of all possible values for a categoric field

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

From the following object

```
items = [{
    title = 'title 1',
    category = 'foo'
  },
  {
    title = 'title 5',
    category = 'bar'
  },
  {
    title = 'title n',
    category = 'bar'
  },
]
```

which

- I receive dynamically at runtime
- can have any length
- where each category field can have one of up to `items.length` values

I want to get the set of all different values for the field `category`.

In the example above, the result of

```
get_all_possible_categories(items)
```

would be

```
['foo','bar'].
```

How can I implement

```
get_all_possible_categories(items) ?
```

Comment: Your object is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just map the values back to an array, using a Set to get unique values

```js
items = [{
    title : 'title 1',
    category : 'foo'
  },
  {
    title : 'title 5',
    category : 'bar'
  },
  {
    title : 'title n',
    category : 'bar'
  }
];

function get_all_possible_categories(arr) {
  return [...new Set(arr.map( x => x.category))];
}

var result = get_all_possible_categories(items);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and map all values of the wanted property.

At the end take an array and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for building a new array. The spread sytax takes the values of an iterable and insert them as parameters.

```js
var items = [{ title: 'title 1', category: 'foo' }, { title: 'title 5', category: 'bar' }, { title: 'title n', category: 'bar' }],
    values = [...new Set(items.map(o => o.category))];

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Thanks. What do the '...' mean? that syntax is new to me.

Comment: It is called spread syntax. Read more here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator